# Invalid CSS/JS references on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm having a problem with my PhoneGap app on iPhone.
The app supports different languages and so my "www" folder has a "de" and a "en" folder with an "index.html" in each. The CSS files are directly in the "www" folder.
So they are referenced in the "index.html" like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.mobile-1.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"/>
```

This works well when i test the "index.html" with FireFox and also with Android... but on iPhone this references seem to be wrong.

Anyone got an idea why?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you create inside your project is not the same as what is created inside your application bundle. Normally everything is put in one big directory. The best thing would be to run this in your simulator. Then go to Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(VERSION)/Applications. Here you will see the applications on your simulator with their GUID. Find the one for your application. Right-click on your application file and select Show Package Contents. Then you can see how the real structure is. Hopefully this will help you with your relative paths inside your html.

Comment: It seems we had a chaching problem... suddenly it worked without any changes -.-

But we have found the package. Thank you for this hint =)
(strukture was the same as everywhere...)